# Сортировка односвязного списка

Tags: c++, сортировка, указатели, списки

Никак не сортирует список, подскажите, где ошибка.

Я создал 2 односвязных списка. Один пустой, в который будет помещен отсортированный список, а второй - исходный односвязный список. С каждой итерацией мы удаляем узел из нашего начального списка и вставляем в нужную позицию отсортированного списка. Сортировка реализуется благодаря 2 функциям. Первая функция (SortedInsert) ищет место в отсортированном списке, куда вставить узел. Вторая функция(InsertionSort) - это непосредственно сама сортировка, в которой отбирается узел из исходного списка, который нужно вставить в новый список и вставляется благодаря первой функции. Так же во второй функции мы учитываем случай, когда нужно вставить узел первым в список

Вот сам алгоритм сортировки вставками:

```
PNode InsertionSort(PNode Head)
{
    if(!Head || !Head->next)
        return Head;

    PNode ptr = Head->next;
    PNode result = Head;
    result->next = NULL;

    while(ptr)
    {
        PNode temp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        result = SortedInsert(result, temp);
    }

    return result;
}
```

С помощью этой функции находит место, куда вставить узел в новом массиве:

```
PNode SortedInsert(PNode Head, PNode NewNode)
{
    if(Head == NULL || Head->data >= NewNode->data)
    {
        NewNode->next = Head;
        Head = NewNode;
        return Head;
    }

    PNode ptr = Head;
    PNode prev = NULL;

    while(ptr != NULL && ptr->data < NewNode->data)
    {
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    NewNode->next = ptr;
    prev->next = NewNode;

    return Head;
}
```

Весь код с добавлением и отображением списка:

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *next;
    };

    typedef Node *PNode;

    void AddNode(PNode &Head, int data);
    void ShowList(PNode &Head);


    int main()
    {
        PNode Head = NULL;
        int node;

        cout << "Enter 5 members of the linked list!" << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cin >> node;
            AddNode(Head, node);
        }

        ShowList(Head);

        cout << endl;

        InsertionSort(Head);

        ShowList(Head);


        return 0;
    }

    void AddNode(PNode &Head, int data)
    {
        PNode NewNode = new Node;
        NewNode->data = data;
        NewNode->next = Head;
        Head = NewNode;
        cout << "Done!" << endl;
    }

    void ShowList(PNode &Head)
    {
        PNode q = Head;
        while(q)
        {
            cout << q->data << " ";
            q = q->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите определение узла списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны по крайней мере в main написать

```
head = InsertionSort(Head);
```

В противном случае вы не выведите сортированный список, так как вы не сохраняете результат работы метода ни в каком головном узле, объявленном в main.

Также имеется побочная проблема в том, что исходный головной узел не изменяется. То есть получится, что два списка указывают на тот же самый начальный узел.

Что касается остального, то, в принципе, функции написаны корректно.

Я бы использовал следующий подход к перемещению одного списка в другой с сортировкой его элементов реализован.

В методах данной реализации указатель на головной узел передается по ссылке. Другой способ - это передавать указатель на главный узел в методы, которые могут изменить главный узел.

Вы можете использовать данную программу в качестве образца для вашей программы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

typedef struct Node
{    
    int data;
    Node *next;
} *PNode;

void push_front( PNode &head, int data )
{
    head = new Node { data, head };
}

std::ostream & display( const PNode &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( PNode current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

void SortedInsert( PNode &head, PNode node )
{
    if ( !head || node->data < head->data )
    {
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        PNode current = head;
        while ( current->next && !( node->data < current->next->data ) )
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        node->next = current->next;
        current->next = node;
    }
}

PNode InsertionSort( PNode &head )
{
    PNode result = nullptr;

    while ( head )
    {
        PNode node = head;
        head = head->next;
        SortedInsert( result, node );
    }

    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    PNode head = nullptr;

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) push_front( head, std::rand() % N );

    display( head ) << std::endl;    

    PNode head2 = InsertionSort( head );

    display( head2 ) << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
7 2 2 1 0 5 4 1 4 1 
0 1 1 1 2 2 4 4 5 7
```

Comment: Да, действительно проблема была в том, что не сохранил возвращаемое, функцией значение. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлександрСорокин Не за что. Так же имелась вторая проблема, головной узел исходного списка при этом не обнуляется.

Answer (score 0):

Вы список разрушаете еще до начала сортировки

```
    PNode result = Head;
    result->next = NULL;
```

Т.е. у первого элемента списка next становится равным NULL

Вы видимо хотели сделать просто `result=NULL`

Comment: Нет, ошибка не в этом. Первоначально отсортированный список состоит из одного узла - первого узла  неотсортированной последовательности. Поэтому я и обрубаю связь с другими узлами. Это же сортировка вставками